# Image + Video + Audio presenter

Tags: windows, linux, office, presentation

I am looking for software similar to PowerPoint, which can present media (image or video + audio) in conjunction with a projector.

**Required features**

- Windows (preferred) or Linux
- Presentation of media

  - Image, video and audio files (no specific format required)
  - Live (no fixed length): I can manually *and* separately* click through the images, video and audio files
  - Timeline: I can arrange my media before doing the presentation. This should avoid searching for the next file in a long list.

*) It would be absolutely perfect if one could bind specific image files to audio files. For example, if image X and audio file Y are combined, clicking on image X will also trigger audio file Y to be started.

Comment: Very complex requirements. I'm not sure if all of these are possible, but have looked into [Prezi](http://prezi.com/)?

Comment: @slybloty Despite being non-free (at least for private presentations which are not publicly viewable), the whole presentation seems to be based on the zoom effect. Unfortunately, this is a no-go, I just want the images to appear (like the standard PowerPoint slide transitions).

Comment: How about a JavaScript/HTML slideshow - you can have total control there but it does require some coding; would that be okay for you? (If so I'll write up a recommendation for a specific slideshow library with a bit of instructions)

Comment: @NickWilde Programming is no problem. The only problem I imagine is the user interface. How can I put the UI elements (buttons, lists, etc.) on the website (i.e. the notebook's screen) while hiding them on the beamer projection? It seems impossible with raw HTML, JS and CSS to me.

Comment: @NickWilde I had an idea some hours ago: using an [extended desktop](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/move-windows-between-multiple-monitors#1TC=windows-7) one could have two browser windows open. One displays the UI, the other one shows the presentation. It doesn't matter where the audio comes from. I would be glad to see your recommendation on that specific library, as you wrote :)