# Fullscreen image slideshow with smooth video capability

Tags: windows, linux, presentation, office, image-viewer

I have got a folder containing

1. an intro video (`001-intro-video.xyz`),
2. some image files (mostly JPG) ordered by their filename: `002-bla.jpg`, …, `098-blub.jpg`, …, and
3. an outro video (`099-outro-video.xyz`).

I want to start with playing back the intro video and proceed by clicking through all the images files. Eventually, the outro video is played back.

#### Requirements

- Plays video files and shows image files, both in definable order

  - I am quite flexible about the file formats.
  - The definable order could equal the alphabetical order of filenames in the folder, for instance. Playlists would also be an acceptable alternative.
- Is able to navigate through the image/video files in a given folder (via mouse or keyboard)
- Smooth transition between video and image files.
  Smooth does not mean interpolation or the like but rather that the software must not require additional clicks or keystrokes except for the navigation key.
- Has a fullscreen mode and scales the video and image files accordingly
- Runs on Windows (strongly preferred) or on any Linux distribution

---

IrfanView in conjunction with its [video plugin](http://www.irfanview.com/plugins.htm) comes very close to my requirements, however the video cannot be played back in fullscreen mode, and there is no smooth transition between the video and image (I have to manually open the first image file).

This software request is similar to my request for an [image + video + audio presenter](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/4054/image-video-audio-presenter?rq=1) &emdash; except for the audio capability which has been outsourced.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using **[Gwenview](https://userbase.kde.org/Gwenview/en)** for this on Linux. This application belongs to the KDE desktop (so it will draw in "some" requirements). It's primarily an image viewer with a lot of extensions, and a.o. also features an automatic slide-show mode.

For your case, the *automatic* slide-show mode might not be fitting. But you could start the application in full-screen with the first image loaded, and then use the arrow keys to navigate the collection – which would be walked by file names in alpha-numerical order. No idea whether playlists are supported (never had any use for such).

- Images larger than the screen would be scaled down to match and fill it completely
- Images smaller than the screen would be presented full-size centered (not sure if you can somehow configure *Gwenview* to "upscale" them)
- Videos would be played when encountered (you can control playback if needed)
- It can deal with most image formats (no idea which ones it can *not* handle, never encountered such)

Being part of KDE, *Gwenview* is available in most (if not all) Linux distributions having KDE available – which should include all *major* distributions.